# Call event handler method from another event handler and pass extra parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

I have two event handler methods.
Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) prompts a user to click ok/cancel. if ok is clicked, another event method is fired - HiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). 
Now, the thing is i have some arguments in Button1_click() method that needs to be passsed to HiddenButton_Click() method. I know, i shouldn't call one event method from another directly, and need to extract that functionality in another method. But, i am not sure the right way to do it.

```
public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var x = 2;
        var y = 4;
       // this event fires another event below.    
       // need to pass x & y to the event below. 
    }

    protected void HiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int x, int y)
    {
        var z = x + y; // need x and y values from above method here.
    }       

}
```

Comment: Where do you find the information that one event handler should not call another event handler directly? BTW `HiddenButton_Click` doesn't look like a [`EventHandler<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx)-Delegate compatible method. To me it looks like a nomal method that's only named like an event handler. Yes I know that you can declare an event using `Action<T, T, T, T>`.

Comment: I read that it is not a best practice to call one event method from another directly. HideenButton_Click is an event method.

Comment: I understand the problem but I think calling the event method handler is not problem because it's only a method. That this method may be registered to an event doesn't change the method itself. That's why I asked for that source of information. In my opinion it's not good practice to raise an event directly from an event handler. But extracting it to another method will not solve the problem of the calling path inside of an event handler. The event is still raised inside of an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make `x` and `y` global variables. This way, you will have access to both variables from all the methods within the same class.

```
    public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        var x,y;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            x = 2;
            y = 4;
        }

        protected void HiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var z = x + y;
        }       

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't make x & y global.

Comment: @user3399326 Maybe you can create a subclass of `EventArgs` that contains x and y and cast inside `HiddenButton_Click` to that event args.